# Yodlee-SDK API Implementation

Tags: php, api, soap, soap-client, yodlee

I have signed a NDA with yodlee and i have got all the SDK files(java,jar and other related docs).

I am a PHP Programmer and from my understanding:

Yodlee is like an engine (almost like Twitter or Facebook) and we need to leverage the API to build different apps

The documents I have gone through is not with good-sufficient information.

They use SOAP-API and I need to use this API.

I have surfed the net for days, and finally posting a question here.

My Question is very simple

1. I have to register a user from my php-form to yodlee using soap-api -> Is this possible
2. If No, is it possible to login from my web-portal to yodlee and access the fin.apps.?

Comment: No1 here to help me out? ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

# 1 is possible. Other clients have done it. You just have to invoke the web services operations from php. We have php sample code.talk to the sales representative about getting access to sample apps plus Yodlee SDK developer forum.

# 2 is not possible.

Comment: Bo Persson - Thanks for the reply. So i will contact the sales rep and ask for sample apps(php) and lemme try the app for my project. thanksa lot in helping me again :)